# Swift 2.0: Type of Expression is ambiguous without more context? SortInPlace

Tags: swift, sorting

This error occured in SWIFT 2.0. There are a lot of similar error messages, but I couldn't match them to my code:

```
class fileObj : Comparable {
    var URL                   = NSURL()   

    var path                  = String()
    var filename              = String()   
    var fileExtension         = String()  
...
}

...
   var images = [fileObj]()  // array of all files (images)

    images.sortInPlace( { $0.URL.absoluteString! > $1.URL.absoluteString! } )   // sort by name
```

The last row causes the error message, indicating, that $0 is wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURL's [`absoluteString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/absoluteString) is non-optional and you're force unwrapping it.

Rewrite the sort as follows

```
    images.sortInPlace( { $0.URL.absoluteString > $1.URL.absoluteString } )
```

Comment: Great. That's it. Thank you.